# Prevent video download during streaming

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

How are Amazon Prime, Netflix, Hotstar able to prevent user from downloading their content while streaming?

Do they use something other than default HTML video player like Adobe shockwave or something?

If so are there any open source video players?

How can I prevent download from 3rd party apps like YouTube downloader (i.e. client must be on app or browser to view the video)?

What are the guidelines let's say if I want to create my video player?

Answer (score 1):

They don’t prevent downloading. Streaming is downloading. If you want people to see the video, you can’t stop them from downloading it.

High value content at companies like Netflix is protected by DRM (widevine, FairPlay, play ready), which controls how the video is decrypted and played.